# how to insert newline in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I've a smarty template code as follows and I want to write the smarty template data line by line into a text file. For this purpose I've to insert a newline at the end of each record(i.e. after the value `$user_test_result.test_result_data.total_obtained_marks`). How should this be achieved? Please help me out to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

```
{if $all_user_test_result}{assign var='sr_no' value=1}{foreach from=$all_user_test_result item=user_test_result key=key}{if $key!='sort_user_name' && $key!='sort_total_obtained_marks' && $key!='sort_no_correct_answers' && $key!='sort_no_wrong_answers' && $key!='sort_no_skipped_questions'}{$sr_no};{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.user_name};{else}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.user_name};{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.test_user_time_used};{else}--{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_correct_answers};{else}-{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_wrong_answers};{else}-{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_skipped_questions};{else}-{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.total_obtained_marks};{else}-{/if}{/if}{assign var='sr_no' value=$sr_no+1}{/foreach}{else}Result not found{/if}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be new line character ("\n") with smarty tags around it placed after the value `$user_test_result.test_result_data.total_obtained_marks` like this {"\n"}. You'll get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm much mistaken, Smarty will output all whitespace from the template directly to the file. So rather than putting all your smarty tags on one line, insert a newline at the appropriate point.

```
{if $all_user_test_result}{assign var='sr_no' value=1}{foreach from=$all_user_test_result item=user_test_result key=key}{if $key!='sort_user_name' && $key!='sort_total_obtained_marks' && $key!='sort_no_correct_answers' && $key!='sort_no_wrong_answers' && $key!='sort_no_skipped_questions'}{$sr_no};{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.user_name};{else}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.user_name};{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.test_user_time_used};{else}--{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_correct_answers};{else}-{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_wrong_answers};{else}-{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_skipped_questions};{else}-{/if}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.total_obtained_marks};{else}-{/if}
{/if}{assign var='sr_no' value=$sr_no+1}{/foreach}{else}Result not found{/if}
```

For readability, you can also include newlines in the template that aren't output by putting them inside `{* comments *}`:

```
{if $all_user_test_result}{*
    *}{assign var='sr_no' value=1}{*
    *}{foreach from=$all_user_test_result item=user_test_result key=key}{*
        *}{if $key!='sort_user_name' && $key!='sort_total_obtained_marks' && $key!='sort_no_correct_answers' && $key!='sort_no_wrong_answers' && $key!='sort_no_skipped_questions'}{*
            *}{$sr_no};{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.user_name};{else}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.user_name};{/if}{*
            *}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_user_data.test_user_time_used};{else}--{/if}{*
            *}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_correct_answers};{else}-{/if}{*
            *}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_wrong_answers};{else}-{/if}{*
            *}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.no_skipped_questions};{else}-{/if}{*
            *}{if $user_test_result.test_user_data.user_status=='Attempted'}{$user_test_result.test_result_data.total_obtained_marks};{else}-{/if}{*
        *}{* Add newline at end of record *}
        {/if}{*
        *}{assign var='sr_no' value=$sr_no+1}{*
    *}{/foreach}{*
*}{else}Result not found{*
*}{/if}
```

Comment: That is what I've encountered recently. Your answer seems to be some workaround there.

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks.